# Right padding to number

Tags: bash, numbers

How can I add trailing pattern in bash after a number?

If number is 100, then I want to output 100xx

If number is 2000, then 2000x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
padding_x () { 
    a=$1;
    printf -v b '%-5s' $a;
    printf '%s\n' "${b// /x}"
}
```

Usage:

```
$ padding_x 100
$ 100xx
$ padding_x 2000
$ 2000x
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want the number 55 printed upto 20 positions with x, use

```
printf "%20d\n" 55 | sed -e 's/ /x/g' -e 's/\(x*\)\(.*\)/\2\1/'
```

Or when you know the formatting options better, sorry, use

```
printf "%-20d\n" 55 | sed -e 's/ /x/g'
```

You can also start with printing too many trailing characters x.

```
xxx=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
printf "%d%s\n"" 55 "${xxx}" | cut -c1-20
```